# Im trying to get data from ion-select using v-model

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

**Using v-for to loop through and get the options. Trying to bind my data to the drinkName variable**

```
<ion-select v-model='drinkName' placeholder="Drink Name">
      <ion-select-option
       v-for='drink, index in drinks'
       :key='index'
       :value="drink.name"
       >{{ drink.name }}
       </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you link your data drinkName pls ? And if you create a function in mounted
If `drinkName` in `console.log()` is an `Observer or object` you need to `stringify` this.
Exemple: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(drinkName))`

```
getValue() {
 console.log(drinkName)
}
```